# Alternate Row shading : Business Objects - WebIntelligence

Tags: business-objects, business-intelligence

I am a n00b on WebI.
Could somebody please tell me how to do alternate row shading in a BO CrossTab.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version you are using, but in XI R2 and above it is automatically applied to a block.  To manually apply it, select the block (dotted border around the entire crosstab), then in the properties under Display, is a set of options called Alternate Row/Color.  Specify the colour for the non-white rows, and the frequency tells XI how often to apply the alternate colour.

In previous versions you can create a new variable with the following code:

```
=Mod(LineNumber(),2)
```

And then add an alerter to the crosstab to set the background colour to your alternative colour whenever this variable equals 1 (i.e. for odd rows).

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a web intelligence report in BO XI 3.0, I need to create blocks with a required alternative colour(239,239,239) in the rows. When i try to change the default colour (240,240,240) of non-white rows to any other colour, the colours are applied to all the body cells in all rows of block. I checked the frequency aswell, it is set to 2. But i'm not sure why is this issue..??